# SASS imports breaks when using Angular Universal

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-universal

Sample app available for download which shows the issue:

https://github.com/chrillewoodz/ng-boilerplate/tree/universal

I'm trying to get angular universal to work but it throws error for a SCSS import in one of the components SCSS files:

```
@import './src/assets/styles/utils/_exports';
```

It works when running it normally without universal but when it runs with universal it treats the import as relative to the component and not root.

So the path becomes:

```
src/app/shared/components/breadcrumbs/src/assets/styles/utils
```

Instead of:

```
src/assets/styles/utils
```

How can I set the path so that it works in both scenarios?

I've done some digging but unable to find similar issues, the only issues that has come up is that SASS doesn't work properly with universal and AOT. Which would be a completely separate issue once I've managed to solve this one.

Comment: I would put /assets/... in the first /src and the would import '/assets/...'

Comment: @Vega I didn't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: sorry, I explain myself:  move /assets folder to the first /src and import it as {/assets//styles/utils}. The place of assets is in /src

Comment: @Vega It's already in the src folder.

Comment: Not really, it's in src/app/shared/components/breadcrumbs/src. Pu it under the first src/

Comment: @Vega you're not understanding the question.

Comment: If you say so...

Answer (score 0):

you have to check from the base which is "" in **tsconfig.app.json** file, so the path should be relative to this  **"baseUrl": ""**, path.if you need your path as "src/assets/styles/utils" you have to change **"baseUrl": "/src"** of "src/assets/styles/utils".can you please share your tsconfig.app.json as asset is parallel to it or may be your folder structure.As you have to check the your SCSS file relative to asset you want to access.